# how to pass a props value in a vuejs scss file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3

I want to pass the props (string) value in my scss file

my component uses the nbColor props which is 'warning' and I want to put this value in my scss file which has the class .colorNb {color: color (nbColor);}
I would like nbColor to take the value nbColor = color: color (warning)

My component call   `<Table :nbColor="'warning'" />`

in my component Table `<span: class = "{colorNb: nbColor}"> {{nb}} </span>`
props  `nbColor: { type: String, required: false }`

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear what you're looking to do, since you're saying you want to pass the value into the **scss file** but from the example it seems like you're wanting to pass it to a tag as a class.

If you're trying to pass it to the scss file, that's not possible.
The file is compiled, so the value would need to be created at compile time. But there are ways to get around that by using css variables or `style`.

If you're looking to pass a variable to the class, then you should be able to to achieve that this way:

```html
<span :class="nbColor"> {{nb}} </span>
```

The following code uses object-based assignment, which uses the key as the value, and the value as a boolean to determine if the value is added or not, so would give you a `<span class="colorNb">` if `nbColor` is set and `<span class="">` if it is not. This is usefull for having state-based classes like `{active:item.isActive, disabled:item.isDisabled}`.

```html
<span :class = "{colorNb: nbColor}"> {{nb}} </span>
```